# Скорость работы инструкции lea

Tags: ассемблер

Я изучаю программирование на Ассемблере и никак не могу понять:

В каких ситуациях для достижения большей скорости выполнения программы лучше использовать lea, а в каких - обходиться стандартными арифметическими операциями (add/sub/div/mul/...)?

Comment: Универсального ответа на такой вопрос нет. x86 (кстати, вы забыли указать x86 в тагах) работает на огромном количестве очень разных аппаратных реализаций. Разговоры о микро-оптимизации имеют мало смысла без указания конкретной модели процессора. Конкретно ваш вопрос активно обсуждался лет 7-8 назад на англоязычном SO. Гуглом легко найти.

Comment: @tum_, хорошо, погуглю, спасибо.
Да, кстати. А что с x64? На нём lea работает как-то иначе?

Comment: Вы о тагах? да и х64 бы сгодилось :) Под тагом `ассемблер` люди спрашивают и про ARM, и про MIPS, и про много чего еще. Чтоб по виду инструкций не гадать, о чём речь - лучше указать.  А ссылка вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323027/lea-or-add-instruction